# If you have a binomial heap of size 14, how can you tell which node is the root node?

Tags: algorithm, sorting, heap, root, max

[image]

Hi guys, I just had a question about this diagram. 
How can I tell which node is the root node and **how would I heapify** something like this?

Thank you.

> Edit: Sorry, when I said heapify I meant make a max heap.
>               Normally with a regular heap, I would go from left to right, starting at the first node that isn't a leaf node and sift downwards. I don't see how I can do that here though.

Comment: I'm not sure what you are asking about. In general case Binomial Heap is not a tree, it is a collection of trees. It has no "root node". Even when it happens to be a single tree, it should be already heapified and the root node is the minimum key node. This is all by definition of Binomial Heap.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're trying to treat the binomial heap as a binary heap, which doesn't work.

A [Binary Heap](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_heap) can be stored in an array without explicit links - the links are implicit in the positions within the array. An unordered array can be "heapified", reordering to make a valid binary heap in O(n) time. That is a key advantage of binary heaps - there's a lightweight implementation that uses memory well.

I've never implemented a [Binomial Heap](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_heap) and though I've studied them, that was a while ago. I'm pretty confident, though, that a binomial heap isn't a binary heap and can't be implemented that way. Binomial heaps have their own advantages, but they don't keep all the advantages of binary heaps. If binomial heaps were universally superior, no-one would care about binary heaps.

IIRC, the normal implementation of binomial trees (on which binomial heaps are based) is that you have a linked list of children for each parent node and a linked list of roots. Those linked lists use explicit links. This is how you support k children per node, with no upper bound on k.

The important extra operation for binary heaps is the merge. If a binomial heap were stored in an array with implicit links, a merge would obviously require lots of copying - copying items from one array into the other for a start. The efficient merge would therefore be impossible - the key advantage of the binomial heap would be lost.

With explicit links, however, combining two binomial trees into one is an O(1) pointer-fiddling operation (adding an item to the head of a linked list), so two binominal heaps can be merged with O(log n) binomial tree merges very efficiently.

It's a bit like the difference between a sorted array and a binary search tree. Sure, the sorted array has advantages, but it also has limitations. Some operations are more efficient when all you have to do is modify a link or two without moving items around in an array. Sometimes you don't need those operations, and it's more efficient to avoid the need for links and just binary search a sorted array, which is equivalent to searching a perfectly balanced binary search tree with implicit links.

Answer (score 1):

This is a binomial heap, it doesn't have one root but a set of roots (because a binomial heap is a set of binomial trees).

What do you mean by "make a max heap" ?
Max heaps and binomial heaps are as close from each other as java and javascript are.

If you extract the minimum n times you can obtain a sorted array which is a max heap. The complexity is O(n*log(n)).

Comment: A "max heap" is *any* heap where the highest priority item is the largest (maximal) item. That could be a binomial heap just as easily as it could be a binary heap. Max. vs. Min. heap is independent of the heap data structure. That said, changing from min heap to max heap is trivial (swap `<` for `>`) so don't believe that Adam is really asking what he's asking either. +1 for the point about sorted arrays, though.

Answer (score 0):

Conceptually, the root should be the only node that has no ancestors - 1 in the case of your diagram.